# Turn specific values of a list into variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

## **Question**

I  have a list,

```
['apples','oranges','peaches','pear']
```

I want the first three items of the list to each automatically become a  separate variable, for example:

```
item1 = 'apples'
item2 = 'oranges'
item3 = 'peaches'
```

I do not want a variable for the value pear, as it is the 4th item in the list.

## **Solution**

I'm currently going through the process of revising my old posts, and I decided to revise this post.

All of the answers to this question are accurate and work just fine. However you can easily get specific items in a list by using their index, which can be better in some situations.

```
>>> list = ['apples','oranges','peaches','pear']
>>> list[0:3] #This displays items in the list in order from 0-3.
['apples', 'oranges', 'peaches']
>>> list[2] #Value is the 3rd item, as the numbers start from 0 and not 1
'peaches'
```

Comment: You mean `item1, item2, item3 = itemlist` ?

Comment: That _is_ converting the list to individual variables

Comment: @khelwood Thank you, that worked. I thought that was converting the variables into a list.

Comment: What happens if your list has 4+ entries? or 2, for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a list:

```
items = ['apples','oranges','peaches']
```

You can unpack the list into three variables using:

```
item1,item2,item3 = items
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a list type, if you assume a fixed length anyways. Just use a tuple or a custom data structure.

Comment: /s/or a custom data structure//

Comment: I know python doesn't really have them (classes to the rescue) and named tuples also suck, but well.

Comment: huh? Tuples are the right answer here (or Enums maybe)

Comment: Yeah, they're a reasonable choice for something with 3 attributes. If it was 10, I would prefer to give things names.

Comment: which is why `collections.namedtuple` is a thing ;)

Comment: Or if you need slightly more functionality but a similar footprint, a class implementing `__slots__`.

Comment: I liked namedtuples once, but they feel non-idiomatic. And it irritated me that defining a namedtuple had a considerable runtime cost. So I would have to define it at startup time and just use it later.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested:

`var1, var2, var3 = list`

But that only works if there are three items in the list. If you have more:

`var1, var2, var3 = list[0], list[1], list[2]`

Comment: or `v1, v2, v3 = lst[:3]`, as long as `len(lst) >= 3`